# Exporting all charts from a Microsoft Excel 2013 file as PDFs

Tags: windows, pdf, microsoft-excel

I am looking for a program that can export all charts from a Microsoft Excel 2013 file as PDF files. If possible, free, can take a batch of files as input, [crop out the surrounding white space](https://superuser.com/q/803300/116475) and works with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: [Image export is possible with VBA](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/export-chart-as-image-file/). The conversion probably has to be done using an extern PNG to PDF converter.